# Extend bing speech API with custom grammar

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I'm developing a webapp and I'm using Microsoft Cognitive Services to add speech to text capabilities. In particular I'm using [Bing Speech API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/overview)

My users use acronyms and no-native English words to refers to some domain specific items. Vanilla Bing Speech API doesn't recognise that acronyms.

Is it possible to add custom words/grammar in Bing Speech API?
Is there a web API alternative to Bing that can be customised with custom words/grammar?
Workaround?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can extend the speech API, but take a look at [Custom Speech Service](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/custom-recognition-intelligent-service-cris), maybe it can satisfy your needs

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to extend the Bing Speech API itself with custom words/grammar. However it is possible to [create a custom language model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-speech-service/customspeech-how-to-topics/cognitive-services-custom-speech-create-language-model), and use this with a [Custom Speech Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/custom-speech-service/). To implement your specific vocabulary. It is for the moment limited to using a REST API with this service. 
The Custom Speech Service endpoints work with the same SDK as Bing Speech API.